# Php sql 3way image upload form

Tags: php, sql, ajax, image, upload

Im currently prepairing a web page and i need to make a form to upload image. It must be possible user to,
1 upload image by url ,
2 upload  image by computer ,
3 upload image by drag and dropping.

I found those code separately from the internet.
But problem is how to combine all of those.

Html Form has 2 input box.
1 image name.
2 image url, upload image button

When user upload image it must be save to folder as name in 1st input box.also it name need to save in sql with the extention.

Can any one help me!

--------------html------------------

```
 <input  name="file_name" placeholder="File Name" class="form-control"  type="text">
```

--------------php----------------

```
if (isset($_POST['add'])){
        $softname=$_POST['file_name'];
```

}

require_once('ImageManipulator.php');

if ($_FILES['fileToUpload']['error'] > 0) {

```
echo "Error: " . $_FILES['fileToUpload']['error'] . "<br />";
```

}
 else {

```
$validExtensions = array('.jpg', '.jpeg', '.gif', '.png','.bmp');


$fileExtension = strrchr($_FILES['fileToUpload']['name'], ".");
// check if file Extension is on the list of allowed ones
if (in_array($fileExtension, $validExtensions)) {
    $newNamePrefix = 'ddownload_';
    $manipulator = new ImageManipulator($_FILES['fileToUpload']['tmp_name']);

    $newImage = $manipulator->resample(250, 250);
    if(isset($_POST['img_url'])){ 
        $url=$_POST['img_url'];
        if (!empty($url)) {
             $data = file_get_contents($url);
            $manipulator = new ImageManipulator( $data);
            // resizing to 200x200 image from url
            $newImage = $manipulator->resample(250, 250);


    }

    // saving file to uploads folder
    $manipulator->save('uploads/img/' . $newNamePrefix . $softname);
    echo 'Thank you! ...';
} else {
    echo 'You must upload an image...';
}
```

}

```
                    $source=$_POST['directlink'];
                    $u_image=$softname; 
                    $filesize=$_POST['size'];
                    $type=$_POST['type'];
                    $description =$_POST['description'];



                   $insert_data="INSERT INTO `softwarelist`(`sid`, `softname`, `image`, `type`, `source`,`description`,`rating`,`filesize`,`user`) VALUES ('','$softname','$u_image','$type','$source','$description','','$filesize','');";
```

-------------end php----------

------------script for drag AND drop image-------

```
<script>

    var files = evt.target.files;
    var files = evt.dataTransfer.files;

    var result = '';
    var file;
    for (var i = 0; file = files[i]; i++) {
        // if the file is not an image, continue
        if (!file.type.match('image.*')) {
            continue;
        }

        reader = new FileReader();
        reader.onload = (function (tFile) {
            return function (evt) {
                var div = document.createElement('div');
                div.innerHTML = '<img style="width: 200px;" src="' + evt.target.result + '" />';
                document.getElementById('filesInfo').appendChild(div);
            };
        }(file));
        reader.readAsDataURL(file);
    }
} else {
    alert('The File APIs are not fully supported in this browser.');
}
```

}

Comment: what did you try ?

Comment: add code.i don't know is it clear to you or not. Actually I try to add this code, i think this link will help https://www.codeforest.net/html5-image-upload-resize-and-crop